# I am looking for some better words to describe someone who likes to speak to themselves

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was watching the episode 272 of Doraemon on Youtube. Nobita wanted to go outside, but the temperature was freezing outside, then Nobita spoke to himself,

> Burr...it's way too cold out

I am looking for some words which can describe Nobita in this situation, that is, Nobita likes to speak to himeself when sometimes his luck is unfavorable.

Comment: We say "He *talks* to himself."

Comment: **genius** is the correct word, apparently... http://elitedaily.com/life/culture/people-talk-to-themselves/1105688/

Comment: Thank you, JavaLatte. Please write it as an answer. I want to vote it up, because that is a good word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact word for the situation that you're talking of but a little research told me that some people with various mental disorders seem to be talking to themselves as in the case of [schizophrenia](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/schizophrenia) but these people hear voices so they may actually be talking to the voices.

Also people with multiple personality disorder seem to talk to themselves, but it is actually their alter personalities talking.

So, as TRoman wrote, saying "He talks to himself." would be best in cases like the one described here. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Pretty sure the question isn't asking about a psychological disorder. People talk to themselves all the time without having schizophrenia.

Answer (score 3):

One good word for something like this is "mutter."  EDIT: As Catija points out, the person that mutters would be a "mutterer".

[**Mutter**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutter?s=t)

1. To utter words indistinctly or in a low tone, often as if talking to oneself; murmur.
2. To complain murmuringly; grumble.

Example:

> The boss told the employee to finish his new assignment before 5:00.  The employee walked away and muttered, "It's already 4:45.  This is ridiculous."

Comment: This isn't the word for the **person** though... In this example, Nobita would be a "mutterer"... a person who mutters.